# MS Word Shrink Text on Overflow for Multiple Tables using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I have a Word doc with multiple tables being populated with info from Excel using mailmerge. The first cell in each table is being populated with a person's name and each cell in the table has a fixed width & height. However, some names are too long that they're overflowing (w/ wrapped text on) so that you cannot see the full name. And because this is a doc that will eventually have 100+ tables, I'd like to use a VBA script after the mailmerge to shrink the font size of those overflowing cells by 1 until there is no overflow in that cell (I'm assuming this would involve some use of a loop).

The tables are to be printed so the name needs to be as large as possible without overflowing and the cell width/height cannot change. Any ideas? I've seen some examples on how to adjust text box overflow but I'm not sure that applies to cells in a table. I'm also very new to VBA so please don't hold back in your explanation, thank you!

(As a side note, I've suggested a workaround using a monospaced font to set font size by character length, but I've been told that's not a possibility and am confined to Arial)

Answer (score 2):

The following macro ensures the output on each label in a mailmerge contains no line wrapping. Text that is loo long to ordinarily fit on a line is fitted to the cell’s width. As named, the macro intercepts the *Edit Individual Documents* command so as to make the process automatic.

```
Sub MailMergeToDoc()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Table, Cll As Cell, Par As Paragraph, sCllWdth As Single, sParWdth As Single
With ActiveDocument
  With .Tables(1)
    For Each Cll In .Range.Cells
      Cll.WordWrap = False
    Next
    With .Cell(1, 1)
      sCllWdth = .Width - .LeftPadding - .RightPadding
    End With
  End With
  .MailMerge.Execute
End With
With ActiveDocument
  For Each Tbl In .Tables
    For Each Cll In Tbl.Range.Cells
      If Len(Cll.Range) > 2 Then
        For Each Par In Cll.Range.Paragraphs
          With Par.Range
            sParWdth = .Characters.Last.Previous.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
            sParWdth = sParWdth - .Characters.First.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
            If sParWdth + .LeftIndent > sCllWdth Then .FitTextWidth = sCllWdth - .LeftIndent
            If .Characters.Last.Previous.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) <> _
              .Characters.First.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) Then
              .FitTextWidth = sCllWdth - .LeftIndent
            End If
          End With
        Next
      End If
    Next
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Choose whatever font and point size is optimal for your needs.

**Note:** the macro requires each output 'line' in the table cells used by the merge to be separated by a paragraph break rather than a manual line break.